# Kernel of an operator defined by a power series

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

Let $K = K(x,y) \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d}\times \mathbb{R}^{d})$. This function defines an integral operator on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$, which I denote by $K$, as follows:
$$(Kf)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}K(x,y)f(y)dy$$
This operator $K$ is proven to be a Hilbert-Schmidt operator, with Hilbert-Schmidt norm $\|K\|_{\mathcal{J}_{2}}$. Analogously, the complex conjugate $\overline{K} = \overline{K(x,y)}$ induces an operator $\overline{K}$ on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$.

Next, consider the operators $A_{K}$ and $B_{K}$ defined by its power series:
$$A_{K} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(K\overline{K})^{n}K}{(2n+1)!} \quad \mbox{and} \quad B_{K} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(K\overline{K})^{n}}{(2n)!}$$
These two series converge in the Hilbert-Schmidt norm, so these operators are well-defined as Hilbert-Schmidt operators. Hence, both $A_{K}$ and $B_{K}$ can be written as integral operators, with integral kernels $A_{K}(x,y)$ and $B_{K}(x,y)$, that is:
$$(A_{K}f)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}A_{K}(x,y)f(y)dy \quad \mbox{and} \quad (B_{K}f)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}B_{K}(x,y)f(y)dy $$

Questions:

- Suppose that $K$ (and, consequently, $\overline{K}$) is symmetric in the sense that $K(x,y) = K(y,x)$ for every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$. Is it true that $A_{K}(x,y) = A_{K}(y,x)$ and $B_{K}(x,y) = B_{K}(y,x)$ as well?
- What about the product $KA_{K}$ and $KB_{K}$? Do they satisfy $(KA_{K})(x,y) = (KA_{K})(y,x)$ and $(KB_{K})(x,y) = (KB_{K})(y,x)$?

Note: the notation $K\bar{K}$ means composite maps:
$$((K\bar{K})f)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}dy K(x,y) \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}dz \overline{K(y,z)}f(z)$$

Comment: What do you mean by $K\overline{K}$ ? I guess the composition of operators.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc yes, products are composition of operators indeed.

Comment: It may be advantageous to consider the functions $S(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty t^{2n+1} (K \bar{K})^nK/(2n+1)!$ and   $C(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty t^{2n} (K \bar{K})^n/(2n)!$. These are of course not the operator cosine and sine functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L^\intercal$ be the transpose operator of $L$. Using the integral you can easily prove that $$(L_1 L_2)^\intercal=L_2^\intercal L_1^\intercal.$$ Indeed,

\begin{align}
\left(L_1L_2\right)^{\intercal}(x, y) = \left(L_1L_2\right)(y, x) &= \int_{\mathbb R^d} L_1(y, z) L_2(z, x) \mathrm d z\\
&= \int_{\mathbb R^{d}} L_2^\intercal(x, z) L_1^\intercal(z, y)\mathrm d z = \left(L_2^\intercal L_1^\intercal\right)(x,y)
\end{align}

Now apply this and you will have $$A_{K}^\intercal = A_{K^\intercal} = A_K$$ same thing for $B_K$

For $KA_K$ and $K B_K$ they are not a prior symmetric, because:

$$\left(KA_K\right)^\intercal = A_{K^\intercal} K^{\intercal} = A_KK.$$

Comment: Ohh I see, using the transpose instead of the adjoint would indeed do the trick. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment that wouldn't fit rather than a proper answer, but we can find "simple" expressions of $A_K(y,x)$ and $B_K(y,x)$ relatively to $A_{K^*}$ and $B_{K^*}$ thanks to the properties of Hilbert-Schmidt operators which might help.

The set $\mathcal{I}_2$ of Hilbert-Schmidt operators is a $*$-ideal, and for an integral operator we even have that the adjoint $K^*$ of $K$ is exactly the integral operator tied to $K^* : (x,y) \mapsto \overline{K(y,x)} = \overline{K}(y,x)$.
Now, the action of $*$ on operators is an antilinear isometry on $\mathcal{I}_2$, therefore bounded, meaning that it commutes with infinite series with respect for the Hilbert-Schmidt norm, hence:
$$\begin{split}A_K^* = \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(K\overline{K}\right)^{n}K}{(2n+1)!}\right)^* &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\left(K\overline{K}\right)^{n}K\right)^*}{(2n+1)!}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{K^*\left(\overline{K}^*K^*\right)^{n}}{(2n+1)!}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(K^*\overline{K}^*\right)^{n}K^*}{(2n+1)!}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(K^*\overline{K^*}\right)^{n}K^*}{(2n+1)!}\\
&= A_{K^*}\end{split}$$
Therefore: $$A_K(y,x) = \overline{A_{K^*}(x,y)}$$
And of course a similar method can be used for $B_K$.

Now the problem is that you picked pure symmetry instead of Hermitian symmetry: in the case of $K(x,y) = \overline{K(y,x)}$ and hence $K = K^*$ we would have been done, but here I don't quite know if you can proceed with this, but hopefully that helps.

EDIT: nevermind, @Kroki is right, the right thing to do in your case is to use the transpose instead of the adjoint. What I said above should be adaptable to the transpose so I'll leave my comment-answer up but Kroki should be the one deserving the bounty.